# How to pass parameters for image as file and name using retrofit in android

Tags: android, file

Hi in the below code below code is my php code.I want to send file from my client .client to sending file as well as filename.I want to sent all the parameters from android app and send to the server.below php code from server based on server I am sending from the client but it is not working

Can any one help me where I did the mistake

example.php:

```
    $data = array(
            '_session'=>$session,
            'file' => $file,
            '_operation' => 'saveRecord',
            'module' => $module,
            'sourceModule' => 'Potentials',
            'sourceRecord' => '13x37913',
            'values' => json_encode(array('notes_title'=>'test','filename' => $_FILES['file']['name'],'assigned_user_id'=>1,"filelocationtype"=>"I", "filestatus"=>1))
        );
    
    below is my api with the following parameters as below
    
Api.java:
    
   

@POST("api.php")
    @Multipart
    Call<SaveContactModule> SaveDocuments(@Part MultipartBody.Part operation,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part session,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part module,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part sourceRecord,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part values,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part sourceModule,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
    
    below activity I am sending to the server but somewhere I did the misatke.
    
    
MainActivity.java:
    
  

     private void saveclosedwon() {
    
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                    sessionId = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
                    String operation = "saveRecord";
                    sourceRecord = "13x53090";
                    String module = "Documents";
                    String sourceModule = "Potentials";
                  //  RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContext().getContentResolver().getType(filePath)), mPhotoFile);
    
                    JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject();
    
                    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", filename, requestFile);
    
                    try {
                        postdata.put("notes_title", notes_title);
                        postdata.put("filename", filename);
                        postdata.put("assigned_user_id", ids);
                        postdata.put("filelocationtype", "I");
                        postdata.put("filestatus", "1");
    
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //String values= postdata.getString(firstname,lastname,jobtile,contacttype,speclization,mobiles,email);
                    final GetNoticeDataService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetNoticeDataService.class);
                    MultipartBody.Part session = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("_session",sessionId);
                    MultipartBody.Part operation_won = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("operation",operation);
                    MultipartBody.Part module_won = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("module",module);
                    MultipartBody.Part sourceRecord_won = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sourceRecord",sourceRecord);
                    MultipartBody.Part sourceModule_won = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("sourceModule",sourceModule);
                    MultipartBody.Part sourceModule_postdata = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("values",postdata.toString());
                    MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "file");
    
    
                    /** Call the method with parameter in the interface to get the notice data*/
                    Call<SaveContactModule> call = service.SaveDocuments(operation_won, session, module_won, sourceRecord_won, sourceModule_postdata, sourceModule_won,body);
    
                    /**Log the URL called*/
                    Log.i("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
    
                    call.enqueue(new Callback<SaveContactModule>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<SaveContactModule> call, Response<SaveContactModule> response) {
    
    
                            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
    
                                SaveContactModule saveContactModule = response.body();
    
    
                                String success = saveContactModule.getSuccess();
                                if (success.equals("true")) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    fragment = new SalesStageFragment();
                                    loadFragment(fragment);
    
                                } else {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
    
    
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<SaveContactModule> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0);
            return;
    
        }
```

Comment: can you post the error from the log? @chandra

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only one encoding annotation is allowed.

Comment: @BrahmaDatta it is giving me this log error

Comment: it means you should either use "field" or "part" annotation but no both in the API @jyoti chandra

Comment: @BrahmaDatta how to change it

Answer (score 0):

As you implemented both multipart and formurlencoded. As per your error it is said that either you should use @Multpart or @FormUrlEncoded but not both at once in the api call. i.e,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
        Call<SaveContactModule> SaveDocuments(@Field("_operation") String operation,
                                     @Field("_session") String session,
                                          @Field("module") String module,
                                          @Field("sourceRecord") String sourceRecord,
                                          @Field("values") JSONObject values,
                                          @Field("sourceModule") String sourceModule,
                                              @Part RequestBody file,
                                              @Part("file") Uri image);
```

or,

```
    @Multipart
    Call<SaveContactModule> SaveDocuments(@Part MultipartBody.Part String operation,
                                 @Part MultipartBody.Part session,
                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part module,
                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part sourceRecord,
                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part values,
                                      @Part MultipartBody.Part sourceModule,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

but not both annotations at once.

Comment: @Part parameters can only be used with multipart encoding. (parameter #7)

Comment: Replace all field params with @part params.

Comment: used only @FormUrlEncoded it is giving me above error

Comment: use Multipart annotation with @part params in the code

Comment: @Part annotation must supply a name or use MultipartBody.Part parameter type. (parameter #7) giving me this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217120/discussion-between-jyothi-chandra-and-brahma-datta).

Comment: for mutltipart you should use MultipartBody.Part